# Microwaving veggies/fish and nutrients

Tags: nutrition, fish, vegetable, microwaves

I usually just put a bowl of frozen veggies in the microwave for dinner, without adding any water. When it's done, there's a considerable amount water in the bowl. Some of that comes from small pieces of molten ice, sure, but some is certainly also from within the veggies. It is slightly colored (mostly green-ish). Doesn't look or taste too great. I've always just poured it in the drain, but am I missing out on nutrients here? Am I literally throwing them away?
Similar thing with fish. Put it dry/frozen in the microwave, take it out in a giant puddle. Again, the liquid is colored/turbid (white-ish). Don't want to lose all those precious nutrients, but it doesn't taste that good, so how much exactly may be in there?

Comment: I doubt there are any studies about this. However, remember that micro-wave does nothing apart heating water.